# Calculate No.Days between two dates which is between two days

Tags: oracle

I have a `CAR REPAIR` Table in which I have `REPAIR_START_DATE` AND `REPAIR_END_DATE` and unique `REPAIR_ID`. I want to calculate total number of days a car was under repair between specific days. I need oracle function. I will be passing From Date and To Date as parameter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interval between two Dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30436933/interval-between-two-dates)

Comment: '-' will be enough if the columns are dates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_days (i_from_date IN DATE, i_to_date IN DATE)
   RETURN NUMBER
IS
   v_days   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT TRUNC (i_to_date) - TRUNC (i_from_date) + 1 INTO v_days FROM DUAL;

   RETURN v_days;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      RETURN 0;
END;
/
```